# SSH connection to localhost ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: mac, ssh, localhost, ssh-keys

Setting up SSH access on local machine for a project.

When I `ssh -v localhost` my connection gets refused. With the following stack-trace.

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Kyle.Welsby/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for localhost
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Kyle.Welsby/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Kyle.Welsby/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Kyle.Welsby/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

My ssh configuration is the standard Mac OS X setup. With the following alterations.

```
# /etc/sshd_config
PermitUserEnvironment yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

# ~/.ssh/config
Host localhost
User Kyle.Welsby
```

Comment: what does your authorization _server_ log say? It would be in `/var/log/auth.log` in Linux, not sure about Mac OS. Also, shouldn't `AuthorizedKeysFile` say `%h/.ssh/authorized_keys` ?

Comment: the issue happend to be `PermitUserEnvironment yes` commented this out and all worked fine-ish.

Comment: You outlined the solution yourself. So post your solution as answer and accept it. Did you really use IPv6 for that localhost connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened to be `PermitUserEnvironment yes` I commented this out and all worked fine-ish.